# how does compilation work exactly on os x

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm

I just started getting into LLVM and clang compilers and the whole thing. I am following the book "Getting started with llvm core libraries". I was under the impression that OS X comes bundled with llvm. However it seems that is not the case. I need to install llvm separately to get command line tools like llc or lli.

So my question is, when I do a "clang" to compile my c/c++ code, what backend does the work of creating the machine code ? My installation shows commands like llvm-gcc and llvm-g++ . Does it mean that it uses gcc internally for creating machine code? And do i need to brew install llvm to switch completely to llvm ?

Comment: No gcc is needed. The normal step is to install Xcode + command line tools. It cames with clang, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `clang`, and plan to do mostly high-level language development (C, C++, ObjC), then I recommend installing the Xcode command line tools. You can get those from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode (or you can install all of Xcode if you prefer).

If you want lower-level tools like `llc`, then my recommendation is brew, as you suggest.

If you're goal is just Mac development, then Xcode is the better solution. If your goal is working on LLVM, then brew is the better answer (or pull [the sources](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) and build it yourself).

If you want both on the same machine, I'd recommend *not* installing the command line tools. Just install Xcode and LLVM. Then you can run the Xcode versions using `xcrun` without colliding with your LLVM installation.

`clang` doesn't use `llvm-gcc` as a backend. It includes LLVM. `llvm-gcc` is a modified version of GCC that integrates with the LLVM backend, which allows programs that expect GCC-specific features to work with LLVM.

Comment: Please, don't bundle an IDE to the question... OP seems to look just for c++ advice. I myself develop for c++ and never touch Xcode. No need for it.